# Jquery Autocomplete is not working on production server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, web-services, autocomplete

I am trying to bind username from database but some how its showing weird error.

ASPX File

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    SearchText();
});
function SearchText() { 
$(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                data: "{'username':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Code Behind is like

```
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
<WebMethod()> _
        Public shared Function GetAutoCompleteData(ByVal username As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim result As New List(Of String)()
        Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=foo; Initial Catalog=db;user id=foo; password=foo;")
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select cust_name from customers where cust_name LIKE '%'+@SearchText+'%'", con)
                con.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", username)
                Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While dr.Read()
                    result.Add(dr("cust_name").ToString())
                End While
                Return result
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
```

I tried checking in firebug. Net XHR. In Post tab it shows

```
JSON


username
    "j"
Source
{'username':'j'}
```

In Response Tab it shows:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Unknown web method GetAutoCompleteData.
Parameter name: methodName
```

Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentException: Unknown web method GetAutoCompleteData.
Parameter name: methodName]
   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceData.GetMethodData(String methodName) +178
   System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule.OnPostAcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +204
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Note the exact same code is working on local machine but not on production server.
In console its showing

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://foo.com/Default.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData"
```

I am not able to understand where i am going wrong. It is showing error alert from the above javascript.
Can Any one help ?

Comment: is the data format correct in AJAX you are sending ?

Comment: Does the method `GetAutoCompleteData` exist on the production server? Is it spelled correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Below is my working code, use it for comparison purpose, it does work in production as well for me, this might help you. Check the data format in ajax.

```
        $( "#txt_item").autocomplete({
            delay: 10,
            minLength: 1, 
            source: function(request, response) {
                $("#txt_item").addClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "cms/cms_gallery.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData", 
                    data: '{term: "' + $("#txt_item").val() + '" }', 
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) { 
                         response(data.d);   
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $("#txt_item").removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
                        alert(textStatus);
                    },
                    search: function () {
                        $("#txt_item").addClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
                    },
                    response: function () {
                        $("#txt_item").removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
                    } 
              });
            }
        });
```

COde Behind:

```
 [WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string term)
{
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(DB.DatabaseConnString());
        string query = "SELECT * from gallery WHERE (unique_no LIKE '%" + My_Helper.FormatStringforDB(term) + "%') limit 5;";
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            conn.Close();
        conn.Open();            
        OdbcDataReader dataReader = new OdbcCommand(query, conn).ExecuteReader();
        if ((dataReader != null) && (dataReader.HasRows))
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                result.Add(dataReader["unique_no"].ToString());
            }
        }
        dataReader.Close();
      return result;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately no Help  :(